# Java: Output String Containing a Key Phrase

Tags: java, string, key, phrase

I am hoping to understand how to extract words from a string that contain a key phrase.

Let's assume that the key phrase is "_01", what is a good method for outputting any word in the input sequence "panorder_01, panorder_02, disorder_01, forkorder_01, forkorder_02, forkorder_03" that contains the key phrase?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split first your string and use the contains method to check of the string contains "_01"

**sample:**

```
String s = "panorder_01, panorder_02, disorder_01, forkorder_01, forkorder_02, forkorder_03";
    String s2 [] = s.split(",");
    for(String s3 : s2)
    {
        if(s3.trim().contains("_01"))
            System.out.println(s3.trim());
    }
```

**result:**

```
panorder_01
disorder_01
forkorder_01
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `input.split(", ")` to split the string into an array of words.

Then use `word.contains("_01")` for each of the words, to see if it contains the phrase.